# Laravel: new records do not start at next id

Tags: laravel, record, auto-increment

Let's say I'm creating a record that has an id of 2. After I deleted that record and I create a new record, the id is 3. I would like it to be 2, since the old one with 2 is gone anyway. How? Or is this not smart to do.

Btw, the id column is a NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Thanks!

Comment: that doesn't seem a good thing to do imo. you can have an different incremental field as an identifier and let that always be the last +1 but not changing the id's like that, will bring tou problems with foreign keys and such

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea, but still you can use this

If you're using MySQL as your database:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

this will reset your auto increment column back to 1 or in your case.
you can refer to this [documentation](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/reseting-mysql-autoincrement-column/) if ever.